# Redis ElastiCache connection error through NestJS Cache Module

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, redis, nestjs, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to connect the CacheModule to a Redis server on AWS ElastiCache but I'm not successful.

I made a connection via redis-cli within EC2 itself and it worked fine, but NestJS does not connect.

```
CacheModule.register<RedisClientOptions>({
      isGlobal: true,
      store: redisStore,
      socket: {
        host: 'master.my-server.use1.cache.amazonaws.com',
        port: 6379,
        tls: true,
      },
      password: 'my-password',
    }),
```

**PM2/Console Error:**

```
node:events:505
PM2        |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
PM2        |       ^
PM2        |
PM2        | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
PM2        |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
PM2        | Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
PM2        |     at RedisClient.on_error (/home/ec2-user/quark-be/node_modules/cache-manager-redis-store/node_modules/redis/index.js:342:14)
PM2        |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/quark-be/node_modules/cache-manager-redis-store/node_modules/redis/index.js:223:14)
PM2        |     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
PM2        |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
PM2        |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
PM2        |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
PM2        |   errno: -111,
PM2        |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
PM2        |   syscall: 'connect',
PM2        |   address: '127.0.0.1',
PM2        |   port: 6379
PM2        | }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the documentation. The documentation takes into account that cache-manager-redis-store supports redis v4, thus leading the reader to believe that they are setting the host and port when this is not read: https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/2333